# Extract portion of filename from path

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to extract 2 section of the filename from a path in 2 string.

e.g.: `"C:\folder\folder\folder\00 00 00 filename.docx"`

All files are named with the same patern. I require to optain 2 fields on the word document that will contain "00 00 00" (fix length) and "filename" (variable length).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
    VarStr = "C:\folder\folder\folder\00 00 00 filename.docx"
    TempArr = Split(VarStr, "\")
    TempArr(UBound(TempArr)) = Mid(TempArr(UBound(TempArr)), 1, Len(TempArr(UBound(TempArr))) - 5) 'remove .docx
    VarFixed = Mid(TempArr(UBound(TempArr)), 1, 8)
    VarVariable = Mid(TempArr(UBound(TempArr)), Len(VarFixed) + 2) 'ignore space

    MsgBox VarFixed & vbCrLf & VarVariable
End Sub
```